# Inserting formula via VBA with reference to another sheet not working. Need workaround

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have created a script which compares columns in two different sheets to sse if the same values are found in both documents.

I do this by inserting a formula via VBA into one of the two documents.

The formula: 
`=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1;'[Filename]SheetName'!$B:$B;0));"NO MATCH","MATCH")`

The problem is that if `SheetName` is anything else than `Sheet(insert number here)` the script doesn't run. I don't know why it won't recognise the sheet, but I need a workaround for this.

VBA Script:

```
Formula1 = "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(" & Chr(col1 + 64) & MyCell1 & ",'[" & fi2 & "]" & SheetName & "'!$" & Chr(col3 + 64) & ":$" & Chr(col3 + 64) & ",0)),""NO MATCH"",""MATCH"")"

Formula2 = "=IF(" & Chr(col1 + 65) & MyCell1 & "=""NO MATCH"",""-"",IF(INDEX('[" & fi2 & "]" & SheetName & "'!$" & Chr(col4 + 64) & ":$" & Chr(col4 + 64) & ",MATCH(" & Chr(col1 + 64) & MyCell1 & ",'[" & fi2 & "]" & SheetName & "'!$" & Chr(col3 + 64) & ":$" & Chr(col3 + 64) & ",0))=" & Chr(col21 + 63) & MyCell1 & ",""MATCH"",""NO MATCH""))"

With Range(myRange1)

        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = Formula1
        .Value = .Value
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .ColumnWidth = 27

End With

With Range(myRange2)

        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = Formula2
        .Value = .Value
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .ColumnWidth = 27

End With
```

Comment: Code looks ok to me, other than the fact that sometimes you add 65 to the column number, sometimes 64 or 63 (you might find R1C1 references easier). What is actually happening with the other sheet names?

Comment: Could you explain to us what some of the variables you are using are referring to? (ie `fi2`)

Comment: You should test your fomulas direcly in a cell before using vba to make sure they actually work

Comment: I've already tried inserting the formula into a cell and it works just fine.

Comment: Are the string formula definitely giving you the correct syntax?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes, I would love to post the entire Script but it was too long.

Answer (score 0):

If `SheetName` is a `WorkSheet` then in your formula you should write `SheetName.Name`
Also, I am not sure about the `'` before and after the workbook and worksheet names.

Comment: Sheetname is defined according to  `SheetName=ActiveSheet.Name` earlier in the script. Regarding the `'`s I just tried to make `Formula1` & `Formula2` look like what a cross file formula would look like.

Comment: Ok. As it has previously been asked to you: can you tell us what your variables are referring to? (MyCell1, fi2, SheetName,...) Without it we cannot try and run the code in the same context than you, so it's hard to guess what the problem is. Also, when you say "the script doesn't run" does this mean a run-time error, a compile-error,.. ?